# Scrapy to follow links from HTML a data-link (not href)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I've got the following HTML:

```
<a data-link="/Category/3/?loadpartial=1">Next</a>
```

If I run my spider, it seems to not use this link (only `a href`).
Is it anyhow possible for Scrapy to follow `data-link` links as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that with a selector like this:

```
response.css("a[data-link]::attr(data-link)").get()
```

Comment: That would be to extract the link.
I'd like my CrawlSpider to be able to find and crawl it.

Comment: You could pass that attribute in the rule link extractor, through the `attrs` parameter. See here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml

Comment: And that was exactly the solution. `attrs=('href', 'data-link',), ` 
Thank you very much!